# SL3 Transparent/Glass Child Window?

Tags: c#, silverlight

Any examples on styling the ChildWindow in Silverlight 3.0 to look like the Windows 7 Aero glass windows?

I've tried changing the background etc., overlaybrush, and overlayopacity properties, including enabling the RootVisual since it is disabled whenever a child window is shown, but no luck so far.

Any examples or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you should share the XAML for the template in the style you have so far?  BTW what do you mean by "enabling the RootVisual"?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a Windows 7 Aero Glass style for you, but you are going to have to replace the default control template for the ChildWindow and style that to get your look instead of just changing properties (Background, OverlayBrush, OverlayOpacity) on the control.

The [MSDN reference page for ChildWindow Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833070(VS.95).aspx) goes over the parts and states model for the ChildWindow and includes the XAML for the default ControlTemplate. I would guess that would be the best place for you to start, and then you'll have to tweak a modified version of the template in Blend to get looking the way you want.

I don't believe there is any need to re-enable the application's RootVisual as long as you still want the standard modal-type behavior of the ChildWindow.

Comment: I'd add, that you may be able to simulate this by not only modifying the opacity and other settings, but adding a background that has a number of effects that are found in Silverlight 3. You could experiment with values using Blend.

- DropShadowEffect
- BlurEffect

Answer (score 1):

Update: I wrote a blog post about this too http://josheinstein.com/blog/index.php/2010/07/windows-7-style-aero-childwindow-template/

I deleted my previous answer because I decided to take another stab at a Windows 7 style Aero ChildWindow. I still can't seem to get a blur effect to work right because blur only blurs the contents of the element it's applied to. If that element has transparency, anything that shows through it is NOT blurred. I guess it could be done with some trickery using a writable bitmap or a pixel shader but I'm not really up for that at the moment.

However, using the awesome "gradient eyedropper" tool in Blend I managed to get my title bar and close button to look very similar to a Windows 7 caption. Screen shot (pretty) and XAML (not so pretty) are below.

[ChildWindow http://josheinstein.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/ChildWindowWindows7Aero.png](http://josheinstein.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/ChildWindowWindows7Aero.png)

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
                    xmlns:s="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk">

  <Style x:Key="AeroWindowCloseButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background">
      <Setter.Value>
        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
          <GradientStop Color="#FFEEB3AC" Offset="0.009"/>
          <GradientStop Color="#FFDA8578" Offset="0.402"/>
          <GradientStop Color="#FFC64D38" Offset="0.459"/>
          <GradientStop Color="#FFC84934" Offset="0.598"/>
          <GradientStop Color="#FFD48671" Offset="0.885"/>
          <GradientStop Color="#FFE8BBAE" Offset="0.943"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF5E5E5E"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="45"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"/>
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
          <Border
            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
            CornerRadius="0,0,3,3">
            <Path
              Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
              Width="11"
              Height="10"
              Stretch="Fill"
              Data="F1 M 6.742,3.852 L 9.110,1.559 L 8.910,0.500 L 6.838,0.500 L 4.902,2.435 L 2.967,0.500 L 0.895,0.500 L 0.694,1.559 L 3.062,3.852 L 0.527,6.351 L 0.689,7.600 L 2.967,7.600 L 4.897,5.575 L 6.854,7.600 L 9.115,7.600 L 9.277,6.351 L 6.742,3.852 Z">
              <Path.Stroke>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                  <GradientStop Color="#FF313131" Offset="1"/>
                  <GradientStop Color="#FF8E9092" Offset="0"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
              </Path.Stroke>
            </Path>
          </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
  <Style x:Key="AeroWindow" TargetType="s:ChildWindow">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF5E5E5E"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="OverlayBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="OverlayOpacity" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
    <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Cycle"/>
    <Setter Property="UseLayoutRounding" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="s:ChildWindow">
          <Grid x:Name="Root">

            <!-- OVERLAY BEHIND CHILDWINDOW -->
            <Grid
              x:Name="Overlay"
              Background="{TemplateBinding OverlayBrush}"
              Opacity="{TemplateBinding OverlayOpacity}"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

            <!-- WINDOW CONTAINER -->
            <Grid x:Name="ContentRoot" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">

              <!-- GLASS BACKGROUND AND BORDER -->
              <!--
          NOTE: This border should not physically contain the rest of the
          window contents because it has an opacity setting that would
          affect all of its children. Instead, a second border is directly
          above it in the z-order and contains the child elements.
          -->
              <Border
                x:Name="Chrome"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                CornerRadius="4"
                Opacity="0.9">
                <Border.Background>
                  <LinearGradientBrush MappingMode="Absolute" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1920,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFADC9E5" Offset="0.010"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFA7C2DC" Offset="0.069"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFB7D2EC" Offset="0.084"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFB7D2EC" Offset="0.146"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFA8C4DE" Offset="0.168"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFB8D3ED" Offset="0.455"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFA6C1DB" Offset="0.518"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFB6D1EB" Offset="0.543"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFA7C2DC" Offset="0.604"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFB7D2EC" Offset="0.618"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFB7D2EC" Offset="0.700"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFABC6E1" Offset="0.722"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFB1CEEA" Offset="0.778"/>
                  </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Border.Background>
              </Border>

              <!-- WINDOW CONTENTS -->
              <!-- 
          NOTE: This element will not have a visible border. The Chrome element
          provides the visible border but this element needs to have a matching
          thickness and corner radius so that the contents of the window are
          "pushed in" by the same amount.
          -->
              <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="4">
                <Grid>
                  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ContentControl
                    Content="{TemplateBinding Title}"
                    Foreground="#FF393939"
                    FontWeight="Bold"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Margin="6,0,6,0"
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="0"/>
                  <Button
                    x:Name="CloseButton"
                    Style="{StaticResource AeroWindowCloseButton}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="1,0,1,1"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Margin="0,0,5,0"
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="1"/>
                  <Border
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                    <ContentPresenter
                      x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                      Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                      HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                  </Border>
                </Grid>
              </Border>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`this article`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833070%28VS.95%29.aspx) on Templating `ChildWindow` with [`this article`](http://silverscratch.blogspot.com/2010/06/chrome-and-glass-theme-part-8.html) on creating `Glass Theme in Silverlight` to create what you want!

Comment: Most experienced designers should be able to customize the ChildWindow via Template, but you won't be able to easily get a true Windows Aero theme because ChildWindow is simply not designed for that. Furthermore, they're greatly lacking in standards-compliance.

I've posted a blog that details the importance of UX (in addition to the glassy styles). Check out http://intersoftpt.wordpress.com/2010/05/21/clientui-part-4-rich-ui-meets-iso-standards/